# WinDefender in Hyper-V Container not working properly

Tags: windows-10, docker-desktop, windows-container, windows-defender, antimalware

According to this thread  [(How) Can I run Windows Defender in a docker container? Getting errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70236130/how-can-i-run-windows-defender-in-a-docker-container-getting-errors/77116212?noredirect=1#comment135947226_77116212) I was able to activate Windows Defender in a “hyperv-isolated” Windows Container (20H2 base) using Docker Desktop 4.20 on Windows 10 21H2.
However, I tried to execute the EICAR test and unfortunately WinDefender did not prevent creation of such a file..
does anyone has passed the EICAR test inside a hyper-v Container?

I created a eicar_test.txt file and passed the EICAR string into it.
On other machines the creation of auch a file both via PowerShell and UI was not possible and the respective anti-malware solution display appropriate warning message